# How to control a roller gate using 2 motors - when one fails the other works

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors

There is a gate which is to be controlled by 2 motors, but one should work and when one fails the other should work. AND THE CONTROLLER USED IS A PLC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest, most efficient solution would be powering the mechanism by both motors simultaneously, connected on the low-torque side of any mechanics - e.g. both propelling the same linear actuator, or the same first gear of a gearbox. Have them with enough surplus power that each can move the gate and idle second motor simultaneously. The gate will open slower with one motor, but it will open just fine.

You can expand on that idea by having the PLC read the current drawn by either of the motors when active, and switch it off (to idle, open contact) if detecting either the current is zero (burnt) or way over the top (short circuit). If the current in both is way higher than normal, but still not at short circuit level, the PLC should switch both motors off and signal gate blocked / mechanism jammed. (similarly, current way low; gearbox broken, motor running without load.)

That way you're keeping the mechanics simple and move most of complex decisions into software.

Now, if you want to save up on electricity, and use cheaper, weaker motors, you'll need either electromagnetic clutches (...and there go all your savings on cheaper motors), or unidirectional (free-wheel) clutches (so that an idle motor isn't pulled by the active one), and forgo simple switching of direction by reversing polarity, in favor of electromechanical gearbox that allows switching direction of the output rotation.

Comment: Or use a differential

Comment: @joojaa: How do you prevent the differential simply transmitting all the torque from the good engine to the broken one, not moving the gate?

Comment: It will never transmit all the torque there. But yes you would make the gate the one with most mechanical advantage.

Comment: @joojaa: How? Extra friction brakes at the motors? The gate is naturally the most "heavyweight" part of the system, taking most torque to move. Idle electric motors are usually very low torque.

Comment: yes but the differential is also a gear so you can change the gear ratio at same cost.

Comment: @joojaa: Gear ratio between the motors will remain 1:1 if you want both to contribute equally; also a pretty short path, just two conical gears in parallel in between, so little friction. The gate would need a quite high ratio to provide torque significantly lower than the motors; and a short path too so that the gears along the way don't contribute too much to friction, and that would necessitate very large gear (making the mechanism unreasonably big) and reducing the speed of the gate to unreasonably low levels.

Comment: You could go with a differential with limited slip, like used in 4x4 vehicles, but once that engages you're down to my initial solution for all practical purposes.

Comment: There are various ways to solve this. You can have a additional gears before the motors reach the differential even a worm gearin which would make it near impossible for the  force to transmit back to the engine.

Comment: @joojaa: Well... that would work - at cost of doubling the mechanical complexity.